# Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token var Comment = React.createClass({...});

Tags: reactjs, syntax

Hey great folks of Stack Overflow. I am learning REACTJS right now. And it's throwing this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: embedded: Unexpected token var Comment = React.createClass({...});

Here's my code: `

```
<body>

<div id="example">

</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
<script type="text/babel">

var Comment = React.createClass({...});

var Board = React.createClass({
  getinitialState: function(){
    return{
      comments: [
        "I like bacon.",
        "Want to get ice cream?",
        "Okay, we've got enough comments now."
      ]
    }
  },
  render: function() {
      return(
        <div className="board">
          {
            this.state.comments.map(function(text, i){
              return(<Comment key={i}>{text}</Comment>);
            })
          }

        </div>
    );
  } 

})
ReactDOM.render(<Board/>, document.getElementById("container"));



</script>








  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://npmcdn.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.js"></script> <!-- older transpiler 5.8.24 works with this app-->

</body>
```

`

I am not sure what's going on here. I'm trying to create a component via var Comment which should have an array which is "var Comment = React.createClass({..});  I don't know why it's not recognizing it as an array that would be used. I would definitely appreciate some help on this, good folks of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing your React code in JSX which is not understood by the script tag. In order to run the React code either use the webpack or browserify to bundle your jsx into a `.js` file and then include that `.js` file in the script tag or in order to test your code use the **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/)** to write your code . It has integration for JSX.

Sample **webpack.config.js**

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
var Board = React.createClass({
  getinitialState: function(){
    return{
      comments: [
        "I like bacon.",
        "Want to get ice cream?",
        "Okay, we've got enough comments now."
      ]
    }
  },
  render: function() {
      return(
        <div className="board">
          {
            this.state.comments.map(function(text, i){
              return(<Comment key={i}>{text}</Comment>);
            })
          }

        </div>
    );
  } 

})
ReactDOM.render(<Board/>, document.getElementById("container"));
```

**index.html**

```
<body>

<div id="example">

</div>

<div id="container">

</div>
<script src="./src/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

You also need to have a package.json to provide all the dependencies.

**[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MhkGQAoc7bc&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABj2GQSlDRjgvXtqfDxKm5b)** is a good video tutorial series that can help you with all the configuration

Comment: Hey Shubham Khatri, thank you so much for your very very detailed response. I can tell from it that you are an expert. I will look into this. Thanks so much again.

Comment: Now when npm install and then type webpack, it's saying "-bash: webpack: command not found" Could this be permissions? When I type "whoami" though, the author is me, so I don't understand yet.

Comment: use `npm install -S webpack` is the command to install webpack provided you have the package.json and `npm install -g webpack` to install webpack globally.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that's what I missed before, and after doing that, it's working properly now. Thanks again Shubham and everyone else who was nice enough to respond! Thank you, good folks of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

JSX syntax is not understood by the script tag. The JSX needs to be compiled to JavaScript. Try out your example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reactjs/69z2wepo/). JSFiddle has integration scripts to work with React.

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Vijay, thanks for answering my question. However, I already have the babel cloudflare script at the bottom. This is what you're talking about, is it not?

Answer (score 0):

You can try moving your JSX code to a new `.jsx` file and referencing that file in your `.html`

Comment: Thank you, Nahush Farkande.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem with you, seems we were watching the same tutorial video :)

Anyway, getinitialState should be getInitialState. Watch out the 4th letter.

Answer (score 0):

Do the one change in your snippet codes which it is given in above section.
Correct minor spelling mistake here.

> *getinitialState*() should be **getInitialState**().

ES5 use getInitialState() to initialize the state variables i.e React.createClass(..).

ES6 use constructor() to initialized the state variables i.e class Comment extends React.Component(..)

Here is another example of ES6, please check out this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="content"></div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>


        <script type="text/babel">

            class CommentBox extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state = {
                editable : false,
                commentMsg : ">>"
                };
            }

            save(event){
                this.setState({commentMsg:event.target.value})
            }
            remove(){
                this.setState({
                    editable:false
                })
            }
            edit(){
                this.setState({
                    editable:true
                })
            }
            renderForm(){
                return (
                <div className="row">
                    <div>{this.props.children}</div>
                    <div><textArea name="commentBox" onChange={this.save.bind(this)}></textArea></div>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger">Save</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>Remove</button>
                    {this.state.commentMsg}
                </div>
                );
            }
            renderHtml(){  
                return (
                    <div className="row">
                    <div>{this.props.children}</div>    
                    <div>{this.state.commentMsg}</div>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-danger" onClick={this.edit.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.remove.bind(this)}>Remove</button>
                    </div>
                );
            }

            render() {
                if(this.state.editable){
                    return this.renderForm(this);
                }else{
                    return this.renderHtml(this);
                }
            }
            }

        class Board extends React.Component{
            constructor(props){
                super(props);
                this.state ={
                    comments:[
                        'Techical Comments',
                        'Wordpress Comments',
                        'Facebook Comments'
                    ]
                }
            }

            render(){
                return(
                    <div className="container-fluid">{
                    this.state.comments.map(function(text,i){
                        return (
                            <CommentBox key={i}>{text}</CommentBox> 
                        );
                    })
                    }
                    </div>
                );
            }
        } 
        ReactDOM.render(
            <Board />
            , document.getElementById('content'))
        </script>
    </body>

    </html>
```